# Como substituir uma coluna de forma condicional no Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe no Pandas e preciso substituir o valor na coluna `semana` de forma condicional. Onde o valor é `53`, quero substituir por `1`.

```
cod; semana;
A; 53;
A; 1;
A; 1;
A; 2;
B; 53;
B; 1;
B; 1;
B; 2;
```

Isso foi o que tentei, mas sem sucesso:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "utf-8", delimiter = ";")

for dado in df['semana']:
    if dado == 53:
        df['semana'].replace(dado, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Acustume-se a **NÃO** fazer `for` em um dataframe. Este seria o último recurso, pois não é nem um pouco performático. Veja este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c)

Para substituir todos que forem igual a 53 por 1, faça:

```
df.loc[df['semana'] == 53, 'semana'] = 1
```

Exemplo:

### Criando DataFrame de teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4], "semana": [1,2,53,2]})
>>> df
   a  semana
0  1       1
1  2       2
2  3      53
3  4       2
```

### Substituindo valores

```
>>> df.loc[df['semana'] == 53, 'semana'] = 1
>>> df
   a  semana
0  1       1
1  2       2
2  3       1
3  4       2
>>>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Paulo!